# How to wrap text in content editable in seperate div elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a content editable div in which what ever numbers i add or paste, each numbers has to wrap inside a div but the current approach gives only errors. 
Could you please provide a solution

http://jsbin.com/jatagisayu/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you change your editable div you can use a regular ng-model instead.

See example her: http://jsbin.com/cazanulije/1/